# TypeError: auroc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task'

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, typeerror, bert-language-model, pytorch-lightning

I was trying to fine tune BERT base uncased on a small dataset of 1.5k fields which is quiet less however while running

```
trainer.fit(model, data_module)
```

when it goes to the 'model' for training which is:

```
class ElectionTagger(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, n_classes: int, n_training_steps=None, n_warmup_steps=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL_NAME, return_dict=True)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
    self.n_training_steps = n_training_steps
    self.n_warmup_steps = n_warmup_steps
    self.criterion = nn.BCELoss()

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
    output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    output = self.classifier(output.pooler_output)
    output = torch.sigmoid(output)
    loss = 0
    if labels is not None:
        loss = self.criterion(output, labels)
    return loss, output

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return {"loss": loss, "predictions": outputs, "labels": labels}

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("test_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    labels = []
    predictions = []
    for output in outputs:
      for out_labels in output["labels"].detach().cpu():
        labels.append(out_labels)
      for out_predictions in output["predictions"].detach().cpu():
        predictions.append(out_predictions)
    labels = torch.stack(labels).int()
    predictions = torch.stack(predictions)
    for i, name in enumerate(LABEL_COLUMNS):
      class_roc_auc = auroc(predictions[:, i], labels[:, i]) ##### ERROR ARISES HERE###
      self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(f"{name}_roc_auc/Train", class_roc_auc, self.current_epoch)

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    optimizer = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=2e-5)
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
      optimizer,
      num_warmup_steps=self.n_warmup_steps,
      num_training_steps=self.n_training_steps
    )
    return dict(
      optimizer=optimizer,
      lr_scheduler=dict(
        scheduler=scheduler,
        interval='step'
      )
    )
```

Instead of implementing, I got an error which says

> TypeError: auroc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task'

It would be great if anyone could provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

in case of using auroc() function, you need to set the task argument to either 'binary', 'multiclass' or 'multilabel'. Or, you can use directly one of the binary_auroc(), multiclass_auroc() or multilabel_auroc() instead of auroc(). See [docs](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/auroc.html#module-interface) for more information.